# Creating multiple records, giving an array of params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I have a model `Hobby`. And I have a `User` model, and user has many hobbies. `Hobby` also has many users. And I have a linking table `UserHobby` (belongs to user, belongs to hobby).

Some user registers on a site, picks some hobbies, and then saves this list. Technically creates an array of records. So on my backend part I have to do something like this:

`UserHobby.create( user: user, hobby: params[:hobbies])`, where `:hobbies` is an array. But it doesn't work this way.

Is there a way to do this without using something like `params[:hobbies].map{ |hobby| UserHobby.create( user: user, hobby: hobby) }` ?

Comment: It can be done better, but are you having an issue with the map? Can you show the associations between the models, please?

Comment: Presumably `params[:hobbies]` is an array of Hobby IDs?

Answer (score 1):

The `map` is fine, but when creating associations use [association methods](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference).

`params[:hobbies]` is a param coming from a form, so presumably it contains an Array of Hobby IDs (perhaps better as `params[:hobby_ids]`). Since these Hobbies already exist in the database, we can simply append them to the user's list of hobbies. This will insert the necessary rows in the join table.

```
user.hobbies << Hobbies.where(id: params[:hobbies])
```

[`user.hobbies` is cached and Rails will only check the database once](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching). If you do `UserHobby.create!(user: user, hobby: hobby)` then `user.hobbies` will be out of date. If you update `user.hobbies` directly then `user.hobbies` will be updated.